# Does C compiler allocates memory for variable name used for declaring an array?

Tags: c, arrays

Let us take an example :--

```
int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int *p = NULL;
```

For the variable arr, will there be any memory allocation ??

Now, what will happen if =>

```
p = arr;
p = &arr;
p = &arr[0];
```

Please help me out to understand this.

Comment: Variable names only exist at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr[10]` creates locations for 10 ints.

```
p = arr ;
p= &arr[0] ;
```

are the same thing.

`&arr` is not something generally useful.  It is a `int (*)[10]` which the compiler should complain about assigning to `p`.

In fact, if you do a little test and print out the addresses of these three:

```
printf("X: %lx %lx %lx\n", (long) arr, (long) &arr, (long) &arr[0]) ;
```

gcc ends up giving you the same thing for all three cases.

```
% ./a.out
X: 7fff906b5b20 7fff906b5b20 7fff906b5b20
```

But where you can really see the difference is if you ask for each item +1 :

```
printf("X: %lx %lx %lx\n", (long) arr, (long) &arr, (long) &arr[0]) ;
printf("X+1: %lx %lx %lx\n", (long) (arr +1), (long) ( &arr +1) , (long) ( &arr[0] +1 )) ;

% ./a.out 
X: 7fff73c105b0 7fff73c105b0 7fff73c105b0
X+1: 7fff73c105b4 7fff73c105d8 7fff73c105b4
```

`arr +1` is four bytes larger than `arr` (the size of an int), as is `&arr[0] +1`, but `&arr +1` is forty bytes larger, the size of the entire array.

Comment: No, `&arr` is *not* an `int**`; it's an `int(*)[10]`, a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s. For `&arr` to be an `int**`, `arr` would have to be a pointer object; it isn't. At least in this case, C and C++ are equally type conscious in this case, requiring a diagnostic for the error (C calls it a "constraint violation", I'm not sure what C++ calls it). But a diagnostic can be a non-fatal warning. It's a difference in how strict the compilers choose to be, not a language issue.

Comment: "`&arr` would assign to an `int **`" -- Still incorrect. There is no `int**` (unless you take the address of `p`, the only `int*` object in the code).

Comment: And now you don't mention that `p = &arr;` is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

This declaration:

```
int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

causes `10 * sizeof (int)` bytes to be allocated to hold the 10-element array object. (No space for any pointer object is allocated.)  The array is initialized as specified.

```
int *p = NULL;
```

creates a single pointer object and initializes it to contain a null pointer value.

```
p = arr;
```

`arr` is an expression of array type. In most contexts, its value is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.  So this assignment causes `p` to point to the first (0th) element of `arr`; `*p == 1`.

```
p = &arr;
```

This is invalid.  `&arr` is of type `int(*)[10]`, or pointer to array of 10 `int`s. `p` is of type `int*`. The types are incompatible. Any conforming C compiler must diagnose this error. (The diagnostic may be a non-fatal warning, but don't let that fool you; it's still an error, what the C standard calls a "constraint violation".)

```
p = &arr[0];
```

This is identical to `p = arr;`. `arr[0]` is the first (0th) element of the array, an `int` object with the value `1`. `&arr[0]` is the address of that `int` object, and is of type `char*`. So this also causes `p` to point to the initial element of the array `arr`.

After this assignment, you can use either `arr` or `p` as the prefix for an indexing operator. The indexing operator is actually defined to take a pointer, not an array, as its prefix, so `arr[0]` uses the result of the array-to-pointer conversion, making it identical to `p[0]`.

But `arr` and `p` still cannot always be used interchangeably. For example, `sizeof arr` gives you the size of the array object (`10 * sizeof (int))`, while `sizeof p` gives you the size of a pointer (`sizeof (int*)`).

Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

(To answer the question in your title, the compiler doesn't, or at least isn't required to, allocate memory at run time for the *name* of an array. It won't allocate 3 bytes of memory at run time because you named your array `arr`, or 22 bytes because you called it `array_with_a_long_name`. It might do so for debugging purposes, but then any such allocated space isn't accessible to your program.)

Answer (score 1):

Storage is not set aside for variable names (arrays or otherwise), except to support debuggers.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of this expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So, taking your three cases:

```
p = arr;
```

The expression `arr` has type "10-element array of `int`".  Since it is not the operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `int`", or `int *`, and its value is the address of the first element of the array.

```
p = &arr;
```

The expression `arr` has type "10-element array of `int`".  Since `arr` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, the conversion above is not performed; instead, the type of the expression `&arr` is "pointer to 10-element array of `arr`", or `int (*)[10]`.  The *value* is the same as the above expression (the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array), but the *types* of the two expressions are different (`int *` vs. `int (*)[10]`), and types matter for things like pointer arithmetic.

```
p = &arr[0];
```

Gives the same type and result as `p = arr;`.

For your array, storage is set aside as follows:

```
         +----+
 arr[0]: |    |
         +----+
 arr[1]: |    |
         +----+
  ...     ...
         +----+
 arr[9]: |    |
         +----+
```

Note that there is no separate storage for a variable named `arr` that points to the beginning of the array; that pointer value is inferred from the array expression as described above.  You can assign to `arr[N]`, but there's no separate `arr` to assign anything to (part of the reason why array expressions are non-modifiable lvalues).